# jQuery Fade in Site/Content Once It's Loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, load, fade

Are there any tutorials or plugins for fading a site into view once its loaded properly, to limit any jarring etc, so the content appears smoothly basically?

I suppose it would be easier if it was just a specific area, as a header or footer will already be cached, from previous pages...

For example a portfolio page with various thumbnails, they only appear smoothly when ready.

Can this be done?

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, wrap your content with a div (e.g. `<div id="main-content">`) and in your css put this:

```
div#main-content { display: none; }
```

Then use this script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main-content').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Is there a fallback for this in case someone doesn't have Javascript enabled?

Answer (score 27):

First, a side point: In general, web designers spend a lot of time trying to improve perceived page load time, getting things shown as quickly as possible. This actively goes the other way, presenting a blank page until everything is ready, which may not be ideal.

But if it's appropriate for your situation:

Since everything visible will be a descendant of `body`, you could load `body` hidden and then fade it in. It would be important to include a fallback for users without JavaScript (typically fewer than 2% at least [according to Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/), but still). So along the lines of:

[(Live Copy)](http://jsbin.com/oxicix/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<!-- This next would probably be in your main CSS file, but shown
     inline here just for purposes of the example
-->
<style type="text/css">
body {
    /* Hide it for nifty fade-in effect */
    display: none;
}
</style>
<!-- Fallback for non-JavaScript people -->
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    /* Re-displays it by overriding the above */
    display: block;
}
</style>
</noscript>
</head>
<body>
...content...
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
// This version runs the function *immediately*
(function($) {

  $(document.body).fadeIn(1000);

})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

A couple of variations on the script part of that, depending on when you want the fade-in to occur:

Wait for "ready" event:

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/oxicix/2)

```
// This version waits until jQuery's "ready" event
jQuery(function($) {

  $(document.body).fadeIn(1000);

});
```

Wait for the `window#load` event:

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/oxicix/3)

```
// This version waits until the window#load event
(function($) {

  $(window).load(function() {
    $(document.body).fadeIn(1000);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

`window#load` fires *very* late in the page load process, after all external resources (including all images) have loaded. But you said you wanted to wait until everything was loaded, so that might be what you want to do. It will definitely make your page seem slower...

Comment: Good .. there are very few who think about fallback. +1 for Nice suggestion

Comment: True. But I would still put body { display: none; } into the CSS file as I try to avoid embedded styles like that as much as possible.

Comment: @sushilbharwani: Yeah. It's typically <=2% of visitors (at least, [that's Yahoo's number](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/)), but still...

Comment: @mmmshuddup: Nit, meet picker. :-) It's an *example*, f'cryin' out loud. Although actually, that makes the fallback easier...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the fadein after window.onload is a nice thought otherwise it wouldnt have looked clean i guess.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :D okayyy okayyy I'll let it go!

Comment: @mmmshuddup: LOL -- actually I took your point on board in the end, because it made fallback easier. :-)

Comment: @T.J Crowder Very decent answer

Comment: Great answer, especially with the fallback option.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to accomplish this is via the Animate.css project. Its pure CSS so there is no need to rely on JS:

https://daneden.me/animate/

Just add the 'animated' and 'fadeIn' class to your parent element and all children will fade in.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#container").fadeIn();
});
```

where container is the id of the div containing your entire content.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div#main-content { display: block; }
```

To make it work with or without Javascript you can use

```
document.getElementById("#main-content").style.display = "none";
```

Then use this script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#main-content').fadeIn();
});
```